# Triangle on top of propto that matches \triangleq

Tags: amsmath, overset

As you can see, neither `\triangle` nor `Delta` look like the triangle in `\triangleq`:

```
x \triangleq y \qquad
x \overset{\triangle}{\propto} y \qquad
x \overset{\Delta}{\propto} y
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this symbol in print?  (What does it mean?)  If it's "accepted", i.e., has appeared in a document published by a recognized publisher, it might be submitted to Unicode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a perfect match but maybe a good enough match.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\mtrian}{\mathrel{\raisebox{-0.1ex}{%
\scalebox{0.8}[0.6]{$\vartriangle$}}}}
\begin{document}
\[x \triangleq y \qquad 
x \overset{\mtrian}{=} y \qquad
x \overset{\mtrian}{\propto} y \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `trimclip` you can obtain a precise match. This approach is inspired by [Vincent's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523109/194703), but does not overpaint anything in white, which may be an issue when you add the symbol over some non-white background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\mtrian}{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\clipbox{0em 1.25ex 0em 0em}{$\triangleq$}}}
\begin{document}
\[x \triangleq y \qquad 
x \overset{\mtrian}{=} y \qquad
x \overset{\mtrian}{\propto} y \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want the exact same triangle, you could define a new command from the `\triangleq` command by placing a white rule over the equal sign, and then adding the `\propto` symbol over that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\newlength{\dimenteq}
\settowidth{\dimenteq}{$\triangleq$}
\newcommand{\trianglepropto}{%
    \triangleq\hspace*{-\dimenteq}%
    \mkern-5mu{\color{white}\rule{\dimenteq}{0.5\dimenteq}}\mkern-5mu%
    \hspace*{-\dimenteq}\propto%
}
\begin{document}
\[
x \triangleq y \qquad x \trianglepropto y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]